# Relying on expected data

Tags: database-design

I'm relatively new to Database Design and I wanted to know the disadvantages to a particular decision I have made in the design of a database for a project. I don't think it will have an effect on the answer, but I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Project:**

We have things called `Bids` which contain `Materials.` Materials can be grouped so I plan on having a `MaterialGroup` table, However, Materials don't have to be apart of a group (they can be `unassigned` if you will). So, instead of making a link-table or making the foreign key nullable I decided to make the first group in the database called `unassigned` and instead of allowing Materials not be grouped I plan to place them in this group if not given a group.

**Question:** Are there any other disadvantages to expecting the first row of the table `MaterialGroup` to be `unassigned` (other than the case of someone failing to insert it there)? From both a practical and theoretical standpoint should I switch to a link-table (or another alternative)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a group that is *not* a group may lead to reporting issues down the road.  For instance, if you want to know the average number of Materials per Group, the results could easily be skewed by the overly large number of `unassigned` group members.

I'd lean towards having a cross reference table that links `Groups` to `Materials`.  So a table named `MaterialsGroupsXRef` that contains `GroupID` and `MaterialID`; any `Material` that is a member of a `Group` has a row in that table.

Any `Materials` that are not a member of a `Group` would not show up in the `MaterialsGroupsXRef` table.  This allows you to easily identify `Materials` that do not have a group.  Likewise, you could easily identify `Groups` with no `Materials`.

Comment: Though I doubt this will be the case it is a good point (Shouldn't be the case since the groups are just made-up most of the time anyways and are really only there in-case of bid-review). I was leaning towards making a link-table anyways so I guess this gives me enough motivation to do so.